# What is it called when an idiom is used so out of place that it is ridiculous?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms, cliche

A spokesman for the UK's Department of Food and Rural Affairs seems to be indicating that either DEFRA, the UK population or the whole of humanity are due to say goodbye to planet earth in 2043.

> A Defra spokesman said: “We are committed through our 25-year environment plan to eliminating avoidable plastic altogether by the end of 2042 **so we leave our planet in a better state than we found it.**

[MSN UKnews](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/uknews/michael-gove-hints-plastic-straw-ban-post-brexit/ar-BBJu8Im?li=BBoPWjQ&ocid=mailsignout)

Is there a word (or phrase) for using a familiar idiom (such as 'leave it as you find it') in such a way that it is ridiculous ?

---

Sample sentence :

_______ is the misuse of an idiom which leads to a ridiculous statement.

Comment: What would have been a clearer less ambiguous message?  "...by 2042 our planet will be in a better place than when we found it in 2017/18"?

Comment: A euphemism, probably.

Comment: The closest I can think of is a "mixed metaphor" but that doesn't quite fit here.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Now that _does_ sound pun-like.

Comment: I don’t think this is a duplicate, and this is not a mixed metaphor. VTR.

Comment: I'm not sure what should make this expression ridiculous, using a trivial expression urging people to keep a campground clean to describe a much more weighty issue, like global warming and plastic floating in the oceans?

Comment: @user5768790 - Agreed. It's an idiom, not a metaphor.

Comment: In this case, possibly, a **non sequitur**?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single best term for the general idea for what you're looking for in your title. But there are many ridiculous things from misuse: a mixed metaphor, a malapropism, a non sequitur, a faulty inference. Your specific example just seems that the author was not thinking logically.

Comment: @Mitch So does 'idiotic' have any connection to 'idiom' ?

Comment: @NigelJ that sounds like a good ELU question. But yes, etymologically [idiom](https://www.etymonline.com/word/idiom?ref=etymonline_crossreference) and [idiot](https://www.etymonline.com/word/idiot?ref=etymonline_crossreference) they're related originally meaning 'of one's own'

Comment: @Mari-Lou A "What would have been a clearer less ambiguous message?" With breathtaking frequency I am unsure that I have anything to contribute but wade right in: he could have said "we leave our planet in better condition than we found it," or more simply "we leave our planet better than we found it."

Comment: You may want to clarify exactly what you find ridiculous about this usage. I can see how it's open to a humorous misinterpretation, but is there some particular aspect that seems wrong to you? Is it the concept of finding and leaving? The use of the word "state"? Just the whole idea that eliminating avoidable plastic might be an improvement for the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Malapropism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/malapropism) - noun - an act or habit of misusing words ridiculously

Answer (score 1):

"We plan to leave our planet in a better state than we found it". Hum. So you found your planet in Rhode Island and you are leaving it in Texas ?

Comment: Just random "states".